# Why neural network outputs unpredictable shape?

Tags: python, keras, output, flatten

I've adapted AlexNet architecture for 1D data as follows:

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1000)
#Instantiate an empty model
model = Sequential()

# 1st Convolutional Layer
model.add(layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=input_length))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=96, kernel_size=11, strides=4, padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='same'))
# model.add(Flatten())

# 2nd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=11, strides=1, padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='same'))
# model.add(Flatten())

# 3rd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv1D(filters=384, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# 4th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv1D(filters=384, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# 5th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='same'))

# Passing it to a Fully Connected layer
model.add(Flatten())
# 1st Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(4096, input_shape=(10,39424)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout to prevent overfitting
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# 2nd Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(4096))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# 3rd Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(1000))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# Output Layer
model.add(Dense(8))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.summary()

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

However,I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_30 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape 
to have value 39424 but received input with shape [10, 23552]
```

I can't figure out why flatten layer gives output of [10, 23552] .. It should give 39424 !!
the problem is the first dense layer received unpredictable data shape from the flatten layer !!
I think the flatten layer must output 1D data not 2D like what it does ([10, 23552])
The model summary is as follows:

```
Model: "sequential_15"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_13 (Embedding)     (None, 4924, 128)         6400      
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_40 (Conv1D)           (None, 1231, 96)          135264    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_47 (Activation)   (None, 1231, 96)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_25 (MaxPooling (None, 616, 96)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_41 (Conv1D)           (None, 616, 256)          270592    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_48 (Activation)   (None, 616, 256)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_26 (MaxPooling (None, 308, 256)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_42 (Conv1D)           (None, 308, 384)          295296    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_49 (Activation)   (None, 308, 384)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_43 (Conv1D)           (None, 308, 384)          442752    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_50 (Activation)   (None, 308, 384)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_44 (Conv1D)           (None, 308, 256)          295168    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_51 (Activation)   (None, 308, 256)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_27 (MaxPooling (None, 154, 256)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_13 (Flatten)         (None, 39424)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_30 (Dense)             (None, 4096)              161484800 
_________________________________________________________________
activation_52 (Activation)   (None, 4096)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_18 (Dropout)         (None, 4096)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_31 (Dense)             (None, 4096)              16781312  
_________________________________________________________________
activation_53 (Activation)   (None, 4096)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_19 (Dropout)         (None, 4096)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_32 (Dense)             (None, 1000)              4097000   
_________________________________________________________________
activation_54 (Activation)   (None, 1000)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_20 (Dropout)         (None, 1000)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_33 (Dense)             (None, 8)                 8008      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_55 (Activation)   (None, 8)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 183,816,592
Trainable params: 183,816,592
Non-trainable params: 0
```

any clues ?

Comment: I guess the error arises during training, right?
Which shape does your input have?
The network itself looks okay, you don't need to specify `, input_shape=(10,39424)` in the first Dense layer after the Flatten layer, but this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: yes it arises after the first epoch. the input shape for the first dense layer should be 39424 (according to model summary) ,  because it comes out of flatten layer . but the error says it receives input as [10, 23552] !! , that's so confusing

Comment: Why are you giving input shape to one of your intermediate layers? model.add(Dense(4096, input_shape=(10,39424))) Input shape is only given to the first layer of the network, and of course this produces the error message.

Comment: yes, it was a mistake,  I shouldn't have defined input shape for that layer. however, the error arose from  a typo which changed the input shapes of training set and test set . when I corrected the typo, the code worked fine.